# ¿Cómo insertar ng-click en un td de forma dinámica y que llame a una función?

Tags: angularjs, date

Necesito crear un calendario y que al hacer click sobre las celdas, guardar el dato que tiene y cambiarle el estilo.

Por ahora sólo saco un mensaje para comprobar si funciona correctamente esta directiva.

El calendario me lo dibuja, pero si hago click sobre las celdas no ocurre nada.

Por ahora mi código es el siguiente:

**Angular**

```
.module('webGPA')
.controller('cambioTurnoController', cambioTurnoController);

function cambioTurnoController($scope,$compile) {

    var vm = this;

    load();

    function load() {

        loadCabeceraTabla();
        loadDetalleTabla2();
    }
    function loadCabeceraTabla() {

        var cabeceraTabla = document.getElementById("cabeceraTabla");

        for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");
            if (i==0) {
                th.innerHTML = "";
            }
            else {
                th.innerHTML = i;
            }
            cabeceraTabla.appendChild(th);
        };
    }
    function loadDetalleTabla2() {

        var descripcionMeses=[
            "Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril",
            "Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto",
            "Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"
        ];
        var detalleTabla ='';

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            var fecha = new Date('2017', i + 1, 0);
            var ultimoDiaMes = fecha.getDate();
            var mes = "0" + (i + 1);

            detalleTabla += '<tr>';

            for (var j = 0; j < 32; j++) {

                var turnoDibujar = "";
                var dia = "0" + j;
                var fechaCurso =
                    dia.slice(dia.length-2)+"/"+mes.slice(mes.length-2)+"/2017";

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    detalleTabla += '<td class="mes">'+descripcionMeses[i]+'</td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    detalleTabla+=
                        '<td class="dia"><span ng-click="vaciar()">'+
                        turnoDibujar+
                        '</span></td>';
                }
            }
            detalleTabla += '</tr>';
        }
        var temp = $compile(detalleTabla)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('detalleTabla2')).append(temp);
    }
    function vaciar() 
    {
        window.alert('Hola');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, en el ng-click debes pasarle como parámetro el elemento seleccionado para obtenerlo en el controlador (o donde quiera que lo necesites).

```
ng-click="select(d)" ng-class="{active: (selectedPosition.value == d )}"
```

Así mismo, creas una función que reciba dicho parámetro y listo.

```
$scope.select = function (value) {
        $scope.selectedPosition = {
            value: value
        };
        alert(value);
    }
```

Adjunto un ejemplo en [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RYlFXFYhEJf85wpi0fv9?p=preview), espero te sirva..

Saludos!